# What happens when RAM is completely full and new process wants to run on an embedded device?

Tags: linux, memory-management, embedded

I am wondering what happens when i try to run a new process on an embedded board running linux with no swap partition or swap file. Normally for linux on PC, it swaps out the pages out of RAM and thus free memory for the new process. Now, embedded boards (take any development board for example), running linux with no swap wants to run a new process with RAM completely full, how does it run a new process?

The boards will have flash memories which have limited life so can't swap frequently even if we implement swap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OOM Killer comes and kills whichever process it thinks needs to be killed.

More information available here: http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer

Comment: you mean to say, basically it kills some other process to run new process?

Comment: It may kill exactly the same process you just started or its parent, e.g. if it has too many forks. Usually you don't want anything like that to happen and it is your job to avoid OOM Killer. Please refer to the link in my answer.

Comment: The Second line of link says "It is the job of the linux 'oom killer' to sacrifice one or more processes in order to free up memory for the system when all else fails." now wat is all else.. I knew about swap space.. and as per this link OOM is the final thing that will happen. Is there any other method ? I guess it should be as per above line.

Comment: No. You either do have some free memory or don't. If you do have free memory or unused swap space, then there is no problem. If you don't, then OOM Killer comes and does his job.

Comment: It seems that OOM killer killed my server - one badly written piece of PHP code brought half of the services down, but not apache...
I'm still investigating and not sure who the culprit is. It is pretty bad though.

Answer (score 2):

The Android system tries to maintain an application process for as long as possible, but eventually needs to remove old processes to reclaim memory for new or more important processes. To determine which processes to keep and which to kill, the system places each process into an "importance hierarchy" based on the components running in the process and the state of those components. Processes with the lowest importance are eliminated first, then those with the next lowest importance, and so on, as necessary to recover system resources.

taken from here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

im assuming android/linux is the same thing for you